# Randomized Character Boundaries JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm doing an AP computer science project where I'm making a game using JavaScript. You move a soccer ball using the arrow keys with the objective of moving it to a goal which is located at (360, 0). It's a 10x10 grid so moving (40, 0) moves one spot. However I added 3 defenders to the grid which move with a randomizer (1-4) and coming in contact with one causes you to lose. The problem is the defenders keep moving off the 10x10 grid so can anyone tell me if there's a way to install boundaries so the randomized characters stay on the 10x10 (or 400px x 400px) grid?

Comment: Please share your code with us, as we can't help you with only this description. Try to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your answer.

Comment: Get your "randomizer" to check if the new location is valid before moving? That's about as much help as we can give without you providing any code.

Comment: Seems like a really easy problem really: `x=Math.max(Math.min(x,400),0)`  and then again for y